# Published documents not accessible from client side

Tags: meteor

Here's the server side code where I publish the documents:

```
function messageData () {
  var fiveHoursAgo = unixTimestampSeconds() - 5 * 60 * 60;
  return Messages.find({unixTimestamp: {$gte: fiveHoursAgo}});
}

function userData () {
  return Meteor.users.find({}, {fields: {'status.online': 1, username: 1}});
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.publish("userData", userData);
  Meteor.publish("messageData", messageData);
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    // code to run on server at startup
  });
```

The subscribe call:

```
  Meteor.subscribe("userData", "messageData");
```

If I put a `console.log(Messages.find({}).fetch());` in the scope of `Meteor.isClient` I see an empty array in my browser console.

If on the server side, I put in a `console.log(messageData().fetch())` I see the two documents I have in my database.

What's also interesting is, when I add the package 'mongol' and look at the subscriptions it recognizes, this is what I see:

[image]

It looks to me as though the two subscriptions are somehow being kludged into one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with differents `Subscribe`.

```
if(Meteor.isClient){
  Meteor.subscribe("userData");
  Meteor.subscribe("messageData");
}
```

Comment: That's so strange that it worked, because I could have swore this gave me strange results in the past... maybe I was using an older version of Meteor at the time.